# How to capture return value of conditional insert in cassandra?

Tags: java, cassandra, datastax, cassandra-2.0, cassandra-2.1

With reference to [Inserting a row only if it does not already exist](https://docs.datastax.com/en/cql/3.1/cql/cql_reference/insert_r.html#reference_ds_gp2_1jp_xj__if-not-exists)

IF NOT EXISTS returns true (if there is no row with this primary key), standard output displays a table like the following:

[image]

In my application code with datastax driver how do i capture the returned value ?

I use [com.datastax.driver.mapping.Mapper.save(T)](http://docs.datastax.com/en/drivers/java/2.1/com/datastax/driver/mapping/Mapper.html#save-T-) whose return type is only **void**

Alternatively I wish to explore [Accessors implementation of datastax](http://docs.datastax.com/en/drivers/java/2.2/com/datastax/driver/mapping/annotations/Accessor.html) but not sure how to capture the return value of conditional insert.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you can only achieve this by using the Accessor interface.

There you can specify that your query should return a `ResultSet` where you can access `wasApplied()` which will tell you if the change has been applied or not.

Comment: See http://docs.datastax.com/en/developer/java-driver/2.1/manual/object_mapper/using/ #manual mapping